# PostGIS table visualization in QGIS without download permission

Tags: qgis, postgis, connection

I'm used to work with PostGIS databases and accessing them from QGIS. I know how to create schemas or grant permissions, but I was wondering if it is feasible to set a user profile that could "view" the information but wouldn't be allowed to download it. Sorry if it's a stupid question, 'cos I guess it's incongruent with the mere essence of the PostGIS-QGIS connections, but I must verify it.

Comment: If this should be possible, it would have to be done in QGIS, since after QGIS has fetched, or rather downloaded, data from PostGIS, PostGIS has no idea what QGIS is doing with it further on. So what you would need is a locked down version of QGIS that makes it impossible to export a PostGIS data layer and also stops all other ways of saving the data e.g. through scripting.

Comment: With plenty of complication if queried directly, or with using a middlelayer software (e.g. GeoServer), you could send (rasterized) *images* of that data (e.g. WMS, WMTS). Only visuals, no data.